# How to enable/disable welcome email from admin configuration in store basis

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, email, magento2.4, system.xml

Hi I referred [this solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/265424/how-to-disable-welcome-email-in-magento2-2) for disabling welcome email and it works perfectly.however i want the around plugin to work only if its enabled from admin backend that too in store basis.

I added etc/adminhtml/system.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>


<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Config:etc/system_file.xsd">
    <system>     
        <section id="customer" translate="label" sortOrder="130" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
            <group id="create_account" translate="label" type="text" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                <field id="welcome_email_disable" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="5" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1">
                    <label>Disable Welcome Email</label>
                    <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Yesno</source_model>
                </field>
            </group>
        </section>
    </system>
</config>
```

etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <customer>
            <create_account>
                <welcome_email_disable>1</welcome_email_disable>
            </create_account>
        </customer>
    </default>
</config>
```

etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

    <type name="\Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification">
        <plugin name="disable-email-notification" type="Vendor\moduleName\Plugin\EmailNotification" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>

</config>
```

Helper/Data.php

```
<?php


declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Vendor\moduleName\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
   
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * Extension enabled config path
     */
    protected const XML_PATH_NO_WELCOME_EMAIL = 'customer/create_account/welcome_email_disable';

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    ) {
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }
    
    /**
     * Retrieve true if extension is enabled.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function moduleEnabled()
    {
       
        return (bool) $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            self::XML_PATH_NO_WELCOME_EMAIL,
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        );
    }
}
```

Plugin/EmailNotification.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\moduleName\Plugin;
use Vendor\moduleName\Helper\Data;
class EmailNotification
{
    public function __construct(
        Data $moduleEnable
    ) {
        $this->moduleEnable = $moduleEnable;
    }

    
        public function aroundNewAccount(\Magento\Customer\Model\EmailNotification $subject, \Closure $proceed)
        {
             if ($this->moduleEnable->moduleEnabled() ===  1) {
                return $subject;
           }
            
        }
   
}
```

even though i am getting the value from moduleEnabled() in EmailNotification.php, this is **not working properly** and new customers created through admin are not visible when trying this code out.Could anyone help me with this ? I needed to enable/disable this feature from backend admin configuration in store basis.

Answer (score 0):

This is I think due to a php error

`===` operator makes a strict comparison type.

so what is happening is that you make

```
true === 1 // false
true == 1 // true
```

So either you compare with the value true, either you remove the bool cast from your method.